# Retrieving data from a socket client-server transaction

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am emulating a client-server socket transaction. Suppose, the client sent some ip packet with

```
status = send(sock, packet, sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr),
                    0);
```

where `sock` is the socket, `packet` points to an ip packet (with ip header struct `iphdr` and tcp header struct `tcphdr`)

Now, on the server side, I want to use some function that retrieves the data in `packet` and displays it. The connection between client and server is correctly set up but when trying to use the `recv` function, I don't get any data. Is `recv` the right function

So on the client side I have

```
packet = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr)+ sizeof(struct tcphdr));
```

and I use

```
send(sock, packet, sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr),
                    0);
```

on the server side, I declared some `char packet[32];` and I used this

```
recv(sock, packet, 32, 0);
```

Edit 2 - here's the code

On the client side

Edit on the client side (to shorten, I didn't mention the included libraries, the `struct` `iphdr`, `tcphdr`, the `in_chksum function`, as well I didn't hydrate the tcp header, for now I just want to test)

```
struct tcphdr tcp_hdr;
struct ip ip_hdr;
#define PORT 23

    int sendmeifyoucan(SOCKET sock, SOCKADDR_IN * sin , int size ){

struct ip * ip = (struct ip *)malloc(sizeof(struct ip));
struct tcphdr * tcp;
char * packet;
int sock_err;
int psize=0, status = 1;

packet = malloc(sizeof(struct ip)+ sizeof(struct tcphdr));
memset(packet, 0, sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));


ip->ip_len = htons(sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + psize);
ip->ip_hl = 5;
ip->ip_v = 4;
ip->ip_ttl = 255;
ip->ip_tos = 0;
ip->ip_off = 0;
ip->ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP;
ip->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
ip->ip_dst.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
ip->ip_sum = in_chksum((u_short *)ip, sizeof(struct ip));



        status = send(sock, packet, sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr),
                0);

        free(packet);

        return 0;
    }


    int main(void)
    {

        int erreur = 0;

        SOCKADDR_IN sin;
        SOCKET sock;

        SOCKADDR_IN csin;
        SOCKET csock;

        int sock_err;


        if(!erreur)
        {
            sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

            if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                printf("La socket %d est maintenant ouverte en mode TCP/IP\n", sock);
                int size = 0;
                /* Configuration */
                sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
                sin.sin_family = AF_INET;                
                sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);


    if(connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("Connection à %s sur le port %d\n", inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr), htons(sin.sin_port));

sendmeifyoucan(sock, &sin,size);
                /* Si l'on reçoit des informations : on les affiche à l'écran */
                            }

    }


                printf("Fermeture de la socket client\n");
                closesocket(csock);
                printf("Fermeture de la socket serveur\n");
                closesocket(sock);
                printf("Fermeture du serveur terminée\n");
            }
            else
                perror("socket");

        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

On the server side

```
#define PORT 23
int main(void)
{

    int erreur = 0;
    SOCKET sock;

    SOCKADDR_IN sin;
    socklen_t recsize = sizeof(sin);
    SOCKADDR_IN csin;
    char buffer[32] = "";

    int sock_err;


    if(!erreur)
    {
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("La socket %d est maintenant ouverte en mode TCP/IP\n", sock);
            /* Configuration */
            csin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
            csin.sin_family = AF_INET;                 
            csin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
            sock_err = bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &csin, sizeof(csin));

            if(sock_err != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                sock_err = listen(sock, 5);
                printf("Listage du port %d...\n", PORT);
            }


            if(sock_err != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                /* Attente pendant laquelle le client se connecte */
                printf("Patientez pendant que le client se connecte sur le port %d...\n", PORT);

                sock = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, &recsize);
            }

            if(recv(sock, buffer, 32, 0) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                    printf("Recu : %s\n", buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Impossible de se connecter\n");
            }

            closesocket(sock);
        }
        else
            perror("socket");

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit 3 - the headers

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define closesocket(s) close(s)
typedef int SOCKET;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PORT 23
```

Comment: Yes you have to use `recv()`. Show us some code please.

Comment: @nouney see my update in my post please

Comment: What returns `send()` and `recv ?()`

Comment: @nouney `send()` returns '48' and recv returns nothing...

Comment: Nothing ? Does it return ? 

I guess you are using a raw socket. Use Wireshark to see if your TCP/IP header is correct. If `recv()` never returns, that means it never received any data.

Comment: When you send a structure as is, it may have padding to align it.  Can you post your iphdr and tcphdr structs. PLUS can you also let us know what type of socket you are opening in the first place?

Comment: @AhmedMasud I used this socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

Comment: Okay so it's a normal TCP socket, that's fine, which means that recv may block. If the peer performs and orderly shutdown recv returns 0 ... so perhaps you are shutting things down on the sender somehow ? can you post your code? If you had an error on recv you'd have a -1;

Comment: @AhmedMasud I have posted my code

Comment: Am i blind or there is not `connect` on the client-side ?

Comment: @nouney sorry for the copy paste issue ;-) I have edited my post

Comment: can you include your headers as well? makes for easier debugging :)

Comment: @AhmedMasud I have just put my headers :)

Comment: Where are you getting the tcphdr and iphdr from? You have not included `<netinet/tcp.h>` and `<netinet/ip.h>` so you will run into sizeof() issues. I am about to downvote your question because you are not posting all of the information. which is not helpful when someone is trying to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @AhmedMasud oh sorry, I didn't want to make to long a post, that's the reason why I didn't fill every informations...

Comment: please give us code that can be compiled easily. it helps a lot. you are asking to point out the mistakes, you need to make sure you give ALL the relevant information otherwise no one can help you. Look at all the WRONG paths we took because you weren't posting the whole thing.  

There is no need to post 50 pages of stuff :) but make sure you post complete context

Answer (score 0):

Okay now I see your problems.

### On client side:

#### First issue (big):

<strike>You are not CONNECTING at all.</strike>

where is your `connect()` call on the client side?

If you want to use SOCK_STREAM you need a connect(2) call

In the code snippet:

```
     if(connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Connection à %s sur le port %d\n", inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr), htons(sin.sin_port));

        /* Si l'on reçoit des informations : on les affiche à l'écran */
                    }
```

your sendmeifyoucan() is OUTSIDE the if block `{` `}` ;

#### 2nd issue

```
    struct iphdr * ip = (struct iphdr *)malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr *));
```

should be

```
    struct iphdr * ip = (struct iphdr *)malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

Otherwise you are in a stack overflow issue.

#### Third issue (not so big)

you are allocating `char *packet` but you are not copying anything on to it it's just memset to 0;

Debug accordingly and try again :)

Comment: thank you for your response. For the first big issue, I had a copy paste issue, I have edited my post. For the rest, I am going to check !

Comment: I still have the same problem, in fact on the server side the response is `Recu : ` but I should get a `0` as the sent packet is set to `0` no ?

Comment: You have bugs dude :) read the code carefully ...also it's a bad idea to use printf for error reporting because stdout is buffered and a crash may not dump out all the buffer so you won't quite know where things have gone wrong. use fprintf(stderr, "..."); for dumping out messages

Comment: @Newben You're sending binary data, but you're printing it as text with fprintf(). You can't do that.

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly, but I still doesn't have any output

Comment: @nos, you're wright but the problem is that I have no output at all. Is that normal ?

Comment: @Newben You are sending `buffer` which is 32 bytes, all with the value 0. Then you try to print it as a string (`printf("Recu : %s\n", buffer);`). Now - what is a string in C ? It is anything up to the first byte with the value of 0. So this will stop at the first byte in your buffer, and print nothing. Note that a byte with the value 0 is different than a byte with the ascii digit '0'

Comment: Ok @nos that was it, thanks a lot, perhaps you could post the answer ;)